# How to count submitted forms and store their information without a DB?

Tags: php, xml, forms

I need way to:

**a)** count how many forms were submitted based on a specific form field value, as well as

**b)** preserve that data for later manipulation if needed, so I guess sending all form data to an email will not be enough.

**About a)**
The idea is to count, how many different form submissions have occurred.

So let's say: Keeping something like: 
Form containing a specific field value A was filled 100 times; 
Form containing a specific field value B was filled 200 times; 
Form containing a specific field value C was filled 500 times;

We will have no more then 5 alternatives here.

I'm thinking about a txt file but, perhaps there is a nicer way ?

**About b)**
I would like to avoid building a database just for this still, I wish not to neglect the fact that, perhaps latter, that information should be retrieved somehow.

I'm thinking about a XML file... ?

Is there better ways? Perhaps using only XML for both cases and deal with this at once?

Any caveat that I should be aware of ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Submit form using `GET`, then parse the web server log for the query string?

Comment: Why the "no database" restriction? You're just trying to build a database out of tools that weren't designed for the same purpose.

Comment: well, because this is a 0 budget request and I intend to write the quicker and simpler solution that my be available for providing this. :) But perhaps a database with a single table will not be that bad hm? :)

Comment: The form is kind of long, so perhaps I will have GET limitations ? And parse the server log seems not as easy as it NOT sound. :) Anyway, I believe I don't mind to have a database. Well, if anyone could be kind enough and provide this answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: There's plenty of '0 budget' databases. If you just need something simple and lightweight, look at SQLite, which doesn't need a dedicated server process, yet still offers a complete (or at least near-complete) ACID implementation.

Comment: @Well I indeed to refer the fact that I will earn 0 money with this. That's why I need a quick and dirty solution. Anyway, and even without being dirty, I believe SQLite may serve the propose. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I would say using sqlite would be an ideal solution.  OK, I admit it is a database - but it is also a text file (which you can move about) and provides you with the means to easily filter and manipulate the data.

Take a look at PEAR::Log http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Log

You can get an awful lot done with a little code.

Sqlite is bundled with PHP5+

There is an Sqlite PDO driver for Pear::Log [here](http://councilsites.co.uk/about/code.htm)